# How to mask password passed as user input while running Jenkins CI pipeline?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In previous versions of Jenkins, I have seen that we have "Password Parameter" to add in a job where when a user pass a value to that while running the job, it wont display the chars and instead they'll be masked. They'll also shown masked in job build history.

I have the same requirement in Jenkins CI pipeline where in jenkinsfile I can mention a parameter which needs to be passed as masked during user input to a python snippet. I did go through the documentation where types of params allowed also has "password", but I dont think it behaves as per my requirement. Can someone help me with the correct syntax or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'dummy', variable: 'USER_AND_PASS')]) {
                    sh '''
                        echo "The credential is ${USER_AND_PASS}"
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see that the username and password are masked in the build output

Comment: Thanks Rich for your reply .... But will this need those passed credentials to be stored somewhere in Jenkins? I basically want masked text field where user input his/her password but shown as masked both before running the job and also in the jenkins console logs.

Comment: Hi Suyash - credentials are store in the Jenkins configuration. They are encrypted. Are you looking to make the password a build parameter?

Comment: Yes Rich, my requirement is to pass a password as a build parameter provided by the user as input. Since, the users can be different, the password will be different and I dont think storing their passwords in jenkins config a good idea.

Comment: Interesting. There are a few posted on how to use a password parameter to a pipeline built. That sounds like what you want.

Comment: @SuyashGupta at the end did you find a solution for this issue?